# What port should I run a GraphQL server on?

Tags: reactjs, express, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

Ports 80 and 443 are in use.

Port 3000 seems to be the default for Apollo Server, but I've examples with people using 4000-5000.

Is there any typical port people are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GraphQL does not have a default port, but in the official documentation the examples are using port **4000** for the GraphQL Server
https://graphql.org/graphql-js/running-an-express-graphql-server/